# Changing the Node Creation Title in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, content-type

Let's say I have a node called "product". When I create such a node, it will always display: "Create product" as the title of the node. How do I change this title WHEN CREATING THE NODE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you mean you have a [*content type*](http://drupal.org/node/21947) "product"?

the "Create product" title when creating a node of type "product" is set in [`node_add($type)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_add/6):

```
// ...
drupal_set_title(t('Create @name', array('@name' => $types[$type]->name)));
$output = drupal_get_form($type .'_node_form', $node);
// ...
```

there are at least 2 options to change this:

- change the translatable string 'Create @name' (indicated by the [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t/6) it is passed through) via

  - [settings.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites--default--default.settings.php/6/source) - search for `locale_custom_strings_`, or
  - http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides
- modify the 'product_node_form' as mentioned by gpilotino (minus the `$form['title']['#title'] = 'foobar'` - you only need the `drupal_set_title('foobar')`). this is a little harder, as you have to [write your own module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules).

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick in your custom module, just be specific to the content type.

```
 function your_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
      if ($form_id == 'contenttype_node_form') {
        drupal_set_title(t("Title you prefer"));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if none of the above has worked:

```
function YOUR-THEME_process_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add') {
    switch(arg(2)) {
      case 'YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE':
       $variables['title'] = t('New Record');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
yourmodule_form_product_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state)
{
  drupal_set_title($foobar);
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work. I use drupal 6? There is not title value in the form object,

Comment: you're right, drupal_set_title should be enough though (I edit the post)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you want to change the words "Create Product"

For a quick and easy solution you can use the [string override][1] module.  It is a little bit of a hack but it is simple and has a nice UI for changing this - there is something to be said for simplicity :-)

[1]: http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides string overrides

Answer (score 1):

I contributed a module that solves this problem. Check out [Node Add Title](http://drupal.org/project/node_add_title).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) { 
  if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  $nid = arg(1);
  .
  .
  .
  .
  drupal_set_title($title);
}
```

}

It's Work.

Thanks,
Latika S.

Comment: This appears to be quite incomplete.  The `$title` var is not defined, and there is no use made of `$nid`.  The `if` should be checking `arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add'`.  See then answer from Francisco Luz.