# Change node creation title on Drupal per Content Type

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I would like to be able to change the node creation title on a per content basis as I have one conent type I want the title to be changed for but leave all other content types to the default.  I a using Drupal 6.

Using the instructions here [Changing the Node Creation Title in Drupal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392573/changing-the-node-creation-title-in-drupal) works fine and dandy, however this will affect all my content types and I only want to change one - I have searched high and low on the Drupal forums, and can't seem to find anything that will help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the [suggestion from the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059933/46149) in that thread you linked?

IIRC, that should do the trick for content type specific manipulation, i.e.:

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == '[yourContenttypeName]_node_form') {
    drupal_set_title(t("Title you prefer"));
  }
}
```